# php wrap specific strings in different tags

Tags: php

I get from server some text which looks like

```
Title ||
text text text
text text text

Title ||
text text text
text text text
text text text
text text text
```

and I need to add different tags and make it looks like

```
<div class="receipt__ingredients__table">
<div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row"><p class="receipt__ingredients__title">Title</p></div>
<div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row"><p>text text text</p></div>
<div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row"><p>text text text</p></div>
</div>

<div class="receipt__ingredients__table">
    <div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row"><p class="receipt__ingredients__title">Title</p></div>
    <div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row"><p>text text text</p></div>
    <div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row"><p>text text text</p></div>
    <div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row"><p>text text text</p></div>
</div>
```

This is my code below

```
$receipt_ingredients = "Title ||
                    text text text
                    text text text

                    Title ||
                    text text text
                    text text text
                    text text text
                    text text text";

$receipt_ingredients = preg_replace('/^(.*?)\s*[|]{2}/m', '<p class="receipt__ingredients__title">$1</p>', $receipt_ingredients);


$receipt_ingredients = '<div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row">'.str_replace(array("\r","\n\n","\n"),array('',"\n","</div>\n<div class='receipt__ingredients__table__row'>"),trim($receipt_ingredients,"\n\r")).'</div>';

echo $receipt_ingredients;
```

but I get structure which looks like

```
 <div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row"><p class="receipt__ingredients__title">Title</p></div>
<div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row">text text text</div>
<div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row">text text text</div>
<div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row"><p class="receipt__ingredients__title">Title</p></div>
<div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row">text text text</div>
<div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row">text text text</div>
<div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row">text text text</div>
<div class="receipt__ingredients__table__row">text text text</div>
```

How to get the structure I need?

Comment: E_TOO_MUCH_TEXT_TEXT_TEXT

Comment: Why are you getting text from the server in that format? I wouldn't use regex for this kind of thing!

Answer (score 0):

Try using explode(). First explode by empty line, after that by || and by newline char in the end.

First create a mapping array, something like :

```
$exploded = array('blocks' => array(
0 => array(
    'title' => '',
    'text' => ''
),
1 => array(
    'title' => '',
    'text' => ''
)
));

// Explode and fill array
$exploded = array();
$blocks = explode('\r\n \r\n', $receipt_ingredients); // NOTE you have to check the newline char coming from the db and use that

foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
    $parts = explode('||', $block);
    $block_array = array(
        'title' => $parts[0],
        'text' => count($parts) > 1 ? $parts[1] : ''
    );

    // You could also simply echo so you do not have to reiterate the array again

    $exploded[] = $block_array;
}
```

This is one approach, usually I use this one in such situations.